# Есть ли какие-нибудь аналоги css scale?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, вёрстка

Есть ли какие-нибудь аналоги css scale? Спрайтовая анимация, реализованная через keyframe, при изменении размера экрана дёргается.

Answer (score 1):

Есть свойство `Zoom`.

```
.css{
  zoom: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через `transform: scale()`

CSS:

```
.css {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```